# How to re-position a VideoView along with its parent?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-view, android-video-player

I have a `Fragment` within a `FrameLayout`. The `Fragment` contains a `VideoView` amongst other things. If I modify the `FrameLayout`'s left position (by calling its `layout(...)` method), the `FrameLayout` and the `Fragment` within it re-position themselves correctly. The `VideoView` within the `Fragment` sometimes re-positions itself but most often stays put.

Does anyone know why the `VideoView` is not re-positioning itself within its parent? Does anyone know how I might be able to get it to do so?

Comment: Did you try `android:padding`.. offsetLeftAndRight() is for temporarily offsetting the views.. such offset will be lost on next layout invalidation..

Comment: The offset method is working okay to move the `FrameLayout` and to keep it offset. (I have overridden my FrameLayout's `onLayout` method to remember and enforce the offset.) Just `VideoView`'s not moving with everything else. The padding approach is no good since I need to move my `FrameLayout` (and its content) partially off screen.

Comment: What do you mean.."sometimes moves and sometimes doesn't".. ? Is there any pattern you see? try to find.. it will be easier to spot the problem root.. if its random, then its very difficult help..

Comment: Thanks again for the response @userSeven7s. In my `Fragment`, as well as a `VideoView`, (beneath it) I have a `ScrollView`. If I'm scrolled a third of the way down on the `ScrollView` (or lower), the `VideoView` strangely moves when I offset the parent `FrameLayout`. Otherwise the `VideoView` stays in its place when the parent `FrameLayout` is offset. Can't seem to see the link though, i.e. why  the `VideoView` would move when the `ScrollView` is scrolled down a significant portion, and not when it's not?!..

Comment: may be the video view is taking the touch..and thats when it gets invalidated and the offset is reset.. have u disabled touch on video view..  wt happens if you remove the scrollview.. and then just swipe over the video view..?

Comment: Have you tryed to use align parent left set to true ?

Comment: Hi userSeven7s, I modified my question slightly as it's not really to do with _offsetting_ in particular but more generally when I re-position my parent FrameLayout (i.e. everything with the FrameLayout moves except for the VideoView). Also, it's not related to taking the touch, as the request to re-position the FrameLayout is made by pressing a button outside of the VideoView.

Comment: Hi Milos, thanks for the suggestion. My `VideoView` _is_ aligned relative to its parent. The parent and everything within it is moving (re-positioning itself). The problem is that the VideoView is not re-positioning itself. Here's a kind of related question with no answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719028

Comment: Are you showing a MediaController with the VideoView ? I thing that your issue cames from the MediaController. PS: i have the same problem, solved it by using customvideoview and custom mediaController. see: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mootwin.bnpetudeeco&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5tb290d2luLmJucGV0dWRlZWNvIl0.

Comment: Hi @Anis, thanks for the response. Yes I am associating a MediaController with my VideoView (and anchoring the MediaController to my activity's main view). What did you do exactly to customise VideoView and MediaController to enable VideoView to be re-position-able?

Comment: Btw @Anis, I couldn't install your app as it is incompatible with all the devices I have. I'm guessing it's specifically for tablets.

Comment: yes its only for tablet. I have created two Custom class using the   VideoView and MediaController sources codes.

Comment: Please can you give me you @mail, i can post Class on the answer.

Comment: adil@thinkincode.co.uk (Thanks! Will test it out.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up in the end. There doesn't seem to be a straightforward workaround for re-positioning a [VideoView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView) or any workaround for that matter. What I'm doing now instead is to play the video full screen in a new activity.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this source code for you VideoView.

```
public class CustomMediaController extends FrameLayout {

    /**
     * Public interface to handle FullScreenRequest. User can implement this
     * interface to make the VideoPlayer Change to FullScreen. The user must
     * handle show/hide of views. If the user do not add a Handler the
     * FullScreen control button will be hided.
     *
     * @author Anis
     *
     */
    public interface FullScreenMediaPlayer {
        /**
         * Event callback when the MediaPlayer request the FullScreen.
         */
        public void onFullScreenRequest();

        /**
         * Event callback when the MediaPlayer request the go back to normal
         * size.
         */
        public void onStreatchScreenRequest();

        /**
         * CallBackEvent when the MediaPlayer is Playing
         */
        public void onPlaying();

    }

    private MediaPlayerControl    mPlayer;
    private final Context         mContext;
    private View                  mAnchor;
    private View                  mRoot;
    private View                  mDecor;
    private ProgressBar           mProgress;
    private TextView              mEndTime, mCurrentTime;
    private boolean               mShowing;
    private boolean               mDragging;
    private static final int      sDefaultTimeout = 3000;
    private static final int      FADE_OUT        = 1;
    private static final int      SHOW_PROGRESS   = 2;
    private final boolean         mUseFastForward;
    private boolean               mFromXml;
    private boolean               mListenersSet;
    private View.OnClickListener  mNextListener, mPrevListener;
    StringBuilder                 mFormatBuilder;
    Formatter                     mFormatter;
    private ImageButton           mPauseButton;
    private ImageButton           mFfwdButton;
    private ImageButton           mRewButton;
    private ImageButton           mNextButton;
    private ImageButton           mPrevButton;

    // Add Streach colomn
    private ImageButton           mFullScreenButton;
    private boolean               isFullSreen;
    private FullScreenMediaPlayer fullScreenListener;

    public CustomMediaController(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mRoot = this;
        mContext = context;
        mUseFastForward = true;
        mFromXml = true;
        isFullSreen = false;

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinishInflate() {
        if (mRoot != null)
            initControllerView(mRoot);
    }

    public CustomMediaController(Context context, boolean useFastForward) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        mUseFastForward = useFastForward;
        initFloatingWindow();
    }

    public CustomMediaController(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        mUseFastForward = true;
        initFloatingWindow();
    }

    private void initFloatingWindow() {

        mDecor = this;
        mDecor.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
        requestFocus();
    }

    private final OnTouchListener mTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
                                                     @Override
                                                     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                                                         if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                                                             if (mShowing) {
                                                                 hide();
                                                             }
                                                         }
                                                         return false;
                                                     }
                                                 };

    public void setMediaPlayer(MediaPlayerControl player) {
        mPlayer = player;
        updatePausePlay();
    }

    /**
     * Set the view that acts as the anchor for the control view. This can for
     * example be a VideoView, or your Activity's main view.
     *
     * @param view
     *            The view to which to anchor the controller when it is visible.
     */
    public void setAnchorView(View view) {
        mAnchor = view;

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        removeAllViews();
        View v = makeControllerView();
        addView(v, frameParams);
    }

    /**
     * Create the view that holds the widgets that control playback. Derived
     * classes can override this to create their own.
     *
     * @return The controller view.
     * @hide This doesn't work as advertised
     */
    protected View makeControllerView() {
        LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mRoot = inflate.inflate(R.layout.media_controller, null);
        initControllerView(mRoot);

        return mRoot;
    }

    private void initControllerView(View v) {
        mPauseButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.pause);
        if (mPauseButton != null) {
            mPauseButton.requestFocus();
            mPauseButton.setOnClickListener(mPauseListener);
        }

        mFfwdButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.ffwd);
        if (mFfwdButton != null) {
            mFfwdButton.setOnClickListener(mFfwdListener);
            if (!mFromXml) {
                mFfwdButton.setVisibility(mUseFastForward ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            }
        }

        mRewButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.rew);
        if (mRewButton != null) {
            mRewButton.setOnClickListener(mRewListener);
            if (!mFromXml) {
                mRewButton.setVisibility(mUseFastForward ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            }
        }

        // By default these are hidden. They will be enabled when
        // setPrevNextListeners() is called
        mNextButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.next);
        if (mNextButton != null && !mFromXml && !mListenersSet) {
            mNextButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        mPrevButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.prev);
        if (mPrevButton != null && !mFromXml && !mListenersSet) {
            mPrevButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        mProgress = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.mediacontroller_progress);
        if (mProgress != null) {
            if (mProgress instanceof SeekBar) {
                SeekBar seeker = (SeekBar) mProgress;
                seeker.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(mSeekListener);
            }
            mProgress.setMax(1000);
        }

        mEndTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time);
        mCurrentTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time_current);
        mFormatBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        mFormatter = new Formatter(mFormatBuilder, Locale.getDefault());

        mFullScreenButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.video_fullscreen);
        installFullScreenListener();
        installPrevNextListeners();
    }

    /**
     * Show the controller on screen. It will go away automatically after 3
     * seconds of inactivity.
     */
    public void show() {
        show(sDefaultTimeout);
    }

    /**
     * Show the controller on screen. It will go away automatically after
     * 'timeout' milliseconds of inactivity.
     *
     * @param timeout
     *            The timeout in milliseconds. Use 0 to show the controller
     *            until hide() is called.
     */
    public void show(int timeout) {

        if (!mShowing && mAnchor != null) {
            setProgress();

            addToFrameAncherLayout();
            mShowing = true;

        }
        updatePausePlay();

        // cause the progress bar to be updated even if mShowing
        // was already true. This happens, for example, if we're
        // paused with the progress bar showing the user hits play.
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(SHOW_PROGRESS);

        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(FADE_OUT);
        if (timeout != 0) {
            mHandler.removeMessages(FADE_OUT);
            mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, timeout);
        }
    }

    private void addToFrameAncherLayout() {

        if ((mDecor != null) && (mDecor.getParent() == null)) {

            if (mAnchor instanceof FrameLayout) {
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
                ((FrameLayout) mAnchor).addView(mDecor, params);
                mDecor.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                // int[] anchorpos = new int[2];
                // mAnchor.getLocationOnScreen(anchorpos);
                //
                // WindowManager.LayoutParams p = new
                // WindowManager.LayoutParams();
                // p.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
                // p.width = mAnchor.getWidth();
                // p.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                // p.x = anchorpos[0];
                // p.y = anchorpos[1] + mAnchor.getHeight() -
                // mDecor.getHeight();
                // p.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
                // p.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL;
                // p.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM;
                // p.token = null;
                // p.windowAnimations = 0; //
                // android.R.style.DropDownAnimationDown;
                // mWindowManager.addView(mDecor, p);
                // Logger.e("Ancher is not a Frame Layout usinf a Blocking Window");
            }
        }
        mDecor.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public boolean isShowing() {
        return mShowing;
    }

    /**
     * Remove the controller from the screen.
     */
    public void hide() {
        if (mAnchor == null)
            return;

        if (mShowing) {
            try {
                mHandler.removeMessages(SHOW_PROGRESS);
                // TODO must be a New View
                if (mDecor != null) {

                    if (mAnchor instanceof FrameLayout) {

                        // ((FrameLayout) mAnchor).removeView(mDecor);
                        mDecor.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        // mWindowManager.removeView(mRoot);
                    }
                }

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                Log.w("MediaController", "already removed");
            }
            mShowing = false;
        }
    }

    static class ProgressHandler extends Handler {
        WeakReference<CustomMediaController> mediaControllerReference;

        ProgressHandler(CustomMediaController mediaController) {
            mediaControllerReference = new WeakReference<CustomMediaController>(mediaController);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            CustomMediaController mediaController = mediaControllerReference.get();
            if (mediaController != null) {

                int pos;
                switch (msg.what) {
                    case FADE_OUT:
                        mediaController.hide();
                        break;
                    case SHOW_PROGRESS:
                        pos = mediaController.setProgress();
                        if (!mediaController.mDragging && mediaController.mShowing
                            && mediaController.mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                            msg = obtainMessage(SHOW_PROGRESS);
                            sendMessageDelayed(msg, 1000 - (pos % 1000));
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private final Handler mHandler = new ProgressHandler(this);

    private String stringForTime(int timeMs) {
        int totalSeconds = timeMs / 1000;

        int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
        int minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
        int hours = totalSeconds / 3600;

        mFormatBuilder.setLength(0);
        if (hours > 0) {
            return mFormatter.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds).toString();
        } else {
            return mFormatter.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds).toString();
        }
    }

    private int setProgress() {
        if (mPlayer == null || mDragging) {
            return 0;
        }
        int position = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        int duration = mPlayer.getDuration();
        if (mProgress != null) {
            if (duration > 0) {
                // use long to avoid overflow
                long pos = 1000L * position / duration;
                mProgress.setProgress((int) pos);
            }
            int percent = mPlayer.getBufferPercentage();
            mProgress.setSecondaryProgress(percent * 10);
        }

        if (mEndTime != null)
            mEndTime.setText(stringForTime(duration));
        if (mCurrentTime != null)
            mCurrentTime.setText(stringForTime(position));

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        show(sDefaultTimeout);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTrackballEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        show(sDefaultTimeout);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        if (event.getRepeatCount() == 0
            && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE)) {
            doPauseResume();
            show(sDefaultTimeout);
            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_STOP) {
            if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mPlayer.pause();
                updatePausePlay();
            }
            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
            // don't show the controls for volume adjustment
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
            hide();

            return true;
        } else {
            show(sDefaultTimeout);
        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }

    private final View.OnClickListener mPauseListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                          @Override
                                                          public void onClick(View v) {
                                                              doPauseResume();
                                                              show(sDefaultTimeout);
                                                          }
                                                      };

    private void updatePausePlay() {
        if (mRoot == null)
            return;

        ImageButton button = (ImageButton) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.pause);
        if (button == null)
            return;

        if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
        } else {
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_play);
        }
    }

    private void doPauseResume() {
        if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.pause();
        } else {
            mPlayer.start();
        }
        updatePausePlay();
    }

    private final OnSeekBarChangeListener mSeekListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                                                            long duration;

                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar bar) {
                                                                show(3600000);
                                                                duration = mPlayer.getDuration();
                                                            }

                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar bar, int progress,
                                                                                          boolean fromtouch) {
                                                                if (fromtouch) {
                                                                    mDragging = true;
                                                                    duration = mPlayer.getDuration();
                                                                    long newposition = (duration * progress) / 1000L;
                                                                    mPlayer.seekTo((int) newposition);
                                                                    if (mCurrentTime != null)
                                                                        mCurrentTime
                                                                                .setText(stringForTime((int) newposition));
                                                                } else {
                                                                    if ((fullScreenListener != null) && (progress > 0)) {
                                                                        fullScreenListener.onPlaying();
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }

                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar bar) {
                                                                mDragging = false;
                                                                setProgress();
                                                                updatePausePlay();
                                                                show(sDefaultTimeout);
                                                            }
                                                        };

    @Override
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        if (mPauseButton != null) {
            mPauseButton.setEnabled(enabled);
        }
        if (mFfwdButton != null) {
            mFfwdButton.setEnabled(enabled);
        }
        if (mRewButton != null) {
            mRewButton.setEnabled(enabled);
        }
        if (mNextButton != null) {
            mNextButton.setEnabled(enabled && mNextListener != null);
        }
        if (mPrevButton != null) {
            mPrevButton.setEnabled(enabled && mPrevListener != null);
        }
        if (mProgress != null) {
            mProgress.setEnabled(enabled);
        }

        super.setEnabled(enabled);
    }

    private final View.OnClickListener mRewListener  = new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                         @Override
                                                         public void onClick(View v) {
                                                             int pos = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                                                             pos -= 5000; // milliseconds
                                                             mPlayer.seekTo(pos);
                                                             setProgress();

                                                             show(sDefaultTimeout);
                                                         }
                                                     };

    private final View.OnClickListener mFfwdListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                         @Override
                                                         public void onClick(View v) {
                                                             int pos = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                                                             pos += 15000; // milliseconds
                                                             mPlayer.seekTo(pos);
                                                             setProgress();

                                                             show(sDefaultTimeout);
                                                         }
                                                     };

    private void installPrevNextListeners() {
        if (mNextButton != null) {
            mNextButton.setOnClickListener(mNextListener);
            mNextButton.setEnabled(mNextListener != null);
        }

        if (mPrevButton != null) {
            mPrevButton.setOnClickListener(mPrevListener);
            mPrevButton.setEnabled(mPrevListener != null);
        }
    }

    private void installFullScreenListener() {
        if (mFullScreenButton != null) {
            mFullScreenButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View aView) {
                    Preconditions.checkNotNull(fullScreenListener,
                            "IllegalStateExeption, FullScreen Button pressed with a nullable Listener");

                    if (isFullSreen) {
                        // send the request to handle normal size;
                        fullScreenListener.onStreatchScreenRequest();
                        isFullSreen = false;
                        updateFullScreenButton();
                    } else {
                        // Send request to go FullScreen
                        fullScreenListener.onFullScreenRequest();
                        isFullSreen = true;
                        updateFullScreenButton();

                    }

                }
            });

            if (fullScreenListener == null) {

                mFullScreenButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } else {

                mFullScreenButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }
    }

    /**
     * Toggle the Full Screen Buttons
     */
    private void updateFullScreenButton() {

        if (isFullSreen) {
            mFullScreenButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.windowmin);
        } else {
            mFullScreenButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.windowmax);
        }

    }

    public void setPrevNextListeners(View.OnClickListener next, View.OnClickListener prev) {
        mNextListener = next;
        mPrevListener = prev;
        mListenersSet = true;

        if (mRoot != null) {
            installPrevNextListeners();

            if (mNextButton != null && !mFromXml) {
                mNextButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if (mPrevButton != null && !mFromXml) {
                mPrevButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }

    public MediaPlayerControl getmPlayer() {
        return mPlayer;
    }

    public void setmPlayer(MediaPlayerControl mPlayer) {
        this.mPlayer = mPlayer;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(int visibility) {

        hide();
    }

    /**
     * @return the fullScreenListener or null if any Listener is registred.
     */
    public FullScreenMediaPlayer getFullScreenListener() {

        return fullScreenListener;
    }

    /**
     * @param aFullScreenListener
     *            the fullScreenListener.
     */
    public void registerFullScreenListener(FullScreenMediaPlayer aFullScreenListener) {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(aFullScreenListener, "FullScreenListener cannot be null ");

        fullScreenListener = aFullScreenListener;
        installFullScreenListener();

    }

    public void removeFullScreenListerer() {
        fullScreenListener = null;
        installFullScreenListener();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see android.view.View#onDetachedFromWindow()
     */
    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {

        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Anis, I've looked through your `CustomMediaController` code and I don't get it. How should this be used? You mentioned in a previous comment that you had code for a custom `VideoView` as well?...

Comment: Hi Anis, I didn't get your e-mail. My email address is: adil@thinkincode.co.uk. Thanks :)