# Android ViewFlipper animation acting weird with videoview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewflipper

I got an XML layout with ViewFlipper and 2 constraint layout as it's child.

1. 1st layout has ImageView
2. 2nd layout has VideoView

I'm using this code to change layout:

```
ViewFlipper flip = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flippy);
flip.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_to_left);
flip.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_to_left);
flip.showNext();
```

this is XML for animation (both same, but different x value)

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shareInterpolator="false" android:fillAfter="true">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="1400"
    />
```

1. The problem is whenever flip.showNext() called, 2nd layout video view already in place when animation starts, I tried textView component, it works but not video view.
2. Is it possible to make 1st layout alpha solid till animation ends?. Whenever flip.showNext() called, 1st layout imageView become transparent (like 50% alpha) when animating. (i didn't put any alpha setting in XML, using android:src in XML for image source).

Thank You

**Edit:**
Just Realized from this [move videoView...using translation animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719028/move-videoview-using-translation-animation) , that translation unable to animate videoView.